# Non-Big O complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I am very confused by the computation of algorithm complexity. For one assignment, we are given the following function and asked to find its complexity.

```
int selectkth(int a[], int k, int n) {
    int i, j, mini, tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      mini = i;
      for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        if (a[j]<a[mini])
          mini = j;
      tmp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[mini];
      a[mini] = tmp;
    }
    return a[k-1];
}
```

The assignment itself asks to "Find the complexity of the function used to find the k-th smallest integer in an unordered array of integers."

Additionally we were asked to write our f function as well as our g function.

From what I understand, for the f function, I would add all the assignments and operations in the function. Do I include the variables k or n in this f function?

As a best guess, I would say that f(n) = 6n + 4(n^2), as there are 6 operations that are looped in the first for loop, followed by 4 operations in the nested for loop.

For further understanding, would the Big O complexity of this function be O(n^2)? I say that because there is a nested for loop, and that would mean a worst case scenario of going through every item, every time.

I apologise if I'm not being clear. I am quite confused with how this works.

Comment: You are correct that two nested loops means `O(n^2)`, imo trying to come up with an equation to show the exact number of instructions is a fool's errand, since some will become more than one CPU instruction and some will be optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: Two nested loops does not necessarily mean `O(n^2)`. Here the outer loop goes from 0 to k-1, which likely leads to `O(kn) `instead of `O(n^2)`. (I say "likely" because I'm making a guess without formal proof.) It's important to be precise with your variables and not always simplify one's thought process to "two loops = quadratic = O(n^2)".

Comment: The inner loop is executed `(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + (n-k)` times, which is obviously `O(kn)`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: it is obvious from the purpose of the function that `k` is in 0..n range therefore `O(k*n) = O(n**2)` regardless of the actual time complexity of the function.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, but `O(kn)` is a tighter bound than `O(n^2)`. One could also say the time complexity is `O(n^3)` and be correct but that would be an unnecessarily loose upper bound.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: if it is not still clear: `k` is not constant. It depends on `n` e.g., `k=n//2` i.e., `O(kn)` is **not** tighter than `O(n**2)`.

Comment: Yes, it *is*. If `k=1` then the function operates in linear time. It is important to capture `k` in the analysis of this function and not replace it with `n`. If you don't have `k` in the result then you lose the ability to see how the runtime of the function varies as `k` varies.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a simple analysis:

Outer loop is doing `k` iterations.

Inter loop is doing `n-1` iterations but it does that `k` times.

So we have `O(k*(n-1)) = O(kn-k)`
Since `k` can be equal to `n` (we can ask for n-th smallest integer in an array) the expression becames `O(n*n-n) = O(n^2-n) = O(n^2)`.

For more help about Big O notation notation check out: http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf